# How to join two tables to select all data with and without the condition in MsSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, left-join, right-join

I have two tables.

## Table_Sale

S_Date 
S_Store 
S_Item_ID
S_Qty

## Table_Return

R_Date 
R_Store 
R_Item_ID
R_Qty

Imagine Table_Sale have 1000 row and Table_Return have 250 rows.I want to do 
  this cindition.
 (S_Date=R_Date and S_Store=R_Store and S_Item_ID=R_Item_ID)

Think there are 150 rows match with that condition. Then there are 850 Rows from Table_Sale and 100 row in Table_Return which are not matching with the condition. Now I want 150+100+850 all data in a one table. How can I make the join sir.?Please anyone help me.

Comment: You would get much better help, if you set up a test-scenario, with just a few rows. Then state the expected output and what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx). Something like this...

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Sale a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_Return b ON a.S_Date = b.R_Date 
                              and a.S_Store = b.R_Store
                              and a.S_Item_ID = b.R_Item_ID
```